# Converting small details from C to Assembly x86

Tags: assembly

Goal: Get this assembly code:

```
 main:
            leal    4(%esp), %ecx
            andl    $-16, %esp
            pushl   -4(%ecx)
            pushl   %ebp
            movl    %esp, %ebp
            pushl   %ecx
            subl    $16, %esp
            movl    $-559038737, -16(%ebp)
            movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
            movl    $1, -8(%ebp)
            jmp     .L2
    .L3:
            movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
            andl    -16(%ebp), %eax
            testl   %eax, %eax
            setne   %al
            movzbl  %al, %eax
            addl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
            sall    -8(%ebp)
    .L2:
            cmpl    $0, -8(%ebp)
            jne     .L3
            addl    $16, %esp
            popl    %ecx
            popl    %ebp
            leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
            ret
```

by fill in the blank:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x = 0x________;
 int result = ______;
 int mask;
 for (mask = _________; mask _______; mask = ________) {
 result += ________;
 }
}
```

What I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x = 0xFFFFFFFFDEADBEEF;
  int result = 0;
  int mask;

  for (mask = 1; mask != 0; mask = mask + 1)
    {
      result += x & mask;
    }
}
```

my assembly code:

```
main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $16, %esp
        movl    $-559038737, -4(%ebp)
        movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
        movl    $1, -8(%ebp)
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
        movl    -4(%ebp), %edx
        andl    %edx, %eax
        addl    %eax, -12(%ebp)
        sall    -8(%ebp)
.L2:
        cmpl    $0, -8(%ebp)
        jne     .L3
        leave
        ret
```

I've been stuck on this for a few hours: How do I add to this C code to have it use commands  `testl, setne, and movzbl`? I know that testl is checking for both operands to be 0, but am unsure of where this fits into the context of the C program. Also, what is the `addl   $16, %esp` at the bottom of main doing? Just pointing to the stop of the stack again?

Comment: Explain what test, setne, and movbl mean to us.  when you do that, you may have a better idea of what you need to do in c.  you have the correct explanation of the esp move - it's unwinding the stack frame that was required to hold the automatic variables.

Comment: The triple `test eax, eax \ setne al \ movzx eax, al` roughly means `something != 0` in C, which is then used as value (you shouldn't see that pattern if that comparison is used as condition for a branch).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same compiler that generated the example assembly code? For one thing, the andl $-16,%esp is rounding esp down to a 16 byte boundary. Is there a compile time option with your compiler to cause this to happen?

The addl $16,%esp near the end of the example code restores the stack from the subl $16,%esp near the start of the code.

The actual stack pointer + 4 is saved in ecx, then ecx is pushed onto the stack near the start of the example code, and restored near the end. Then esp is restored using leal $-4(%ecx),%esp.

All of the above are related to how your compiler handles function prologues and epilogues.

The rest of the assembly code example translates into the C code example, you just need to fill in the blanks as asked.